# creating methods that doesn't depend on a object

Tags: c++, methods, include

How can I create bunch of methods that doesn't depend on any object ( in my file there is no classes , no objects , no main , nothing but the methods) all in one cpp/hpp file and how to declare them ?

Comment: If you have no classes, you have no methods.  </pedantry>

Comment: And by the way, you must have a `main` somewhere in order for your program to be a valid C++ construction.

Comment: @JohnDibling so dll's aren't valid C++ "constructions"?

Comment: "Constructions" was the wrong word.  DLLs run in the scope of an appllication which, if written in C++, has a `main`.  I should have said program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be public, i.e. available in multiple translation units, the best way is to include them in a `namespace`, declare them in the header and implement them in a single implementation file:

```
//functions.h

namespace MyFunctions
{
   void foo();
   void goo();
}

//functions.cpp

namespace MyFunctions
{
   void foo() {}
   void goo() {}
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

If you provide the definition in the header, you should mark them `inline`, otherwise including that header in multiple translation units might result in a linker error:

```
//functions.h
inline void foo() {  
    //..
}
inline void goo() { 
    //..
}
```

If you only want them available in a translation unit, define them in that implementation file in an anonymous namespace (or declare them `static`):

```
//fileThatUsesFunctions.cpp

namespace
{
    void foo() {}
    void goo() {}
}
```

Comment: It's funny that the asker used the word "method" and everyone else started using it too :)

Comment: why two files ? why can't I just declare them static and implement them in the same hpp file ?

Comment: @Glolita you can implement them in the same header file, but that is not how it's usually done (to seperate interface from implementation). But if you do, **don't** mark them `static`, or every file that `#include`s it will get its own version.

Comment: @Glolita if you want to implement them in the header, mark them as inline, not static, otherwise the code will get duplicated.

Comment: @SethCarnegie if you don't mark them `static` or `inline`, you'll probably run into liker errors. See updated answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore what do you mean by "translation unit" when you say "If you only want them available in a translation unit, define them in that implementation file in an anonymous namespace (or declare them static)" cause I certainly don't want to declare a new namespace

Comment: @Glolita you can declare a namespace without a name in a `.cpp` file (you can do it in any file but you don't want them in header files) and that way other files can't access those functions (by writing a prototype or whatever and using that).

Comment: @Glolita a translation unit is basically an implementation file (.cpp) with all its included files (& recursively included files).

Answer (score 4):

Create a `namespace`. Something like this:

**Utils.h**

```
namespace Utils
{
   void myMethod();
}
```

**Utils.cpp**

```
namespace Utils
{
  void myMethod()
  {
    //Implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already creating a new namespace with classes that needs these free functions, so I don't need another namespace to just put in it a couple of free functions ,so I was thinking why can't I just implement them as inline methods in a hpp file that I can include it later in the other classes ????

Comment: @Glolita: Can't you put these functions in the same namespace as those classes. Otherwise, if the functions are small enough you can make it inline.

Comment: yes this what I was asking about , having them within the same namespace but making them as inline functions in a hpp file under the same namespace

Answer (score 1):

To define a function that doesn't depend on an object simply declare them directly.

```
// MyFile.h
int some_function();

// MyFile.cpp

int some_function() {
  return 42;
}
```

Using C++ though it would be a good idea to declare them in a namespace though.  This doesn't give them a dependcy on an object but does reduce global namespace pollution

```
// MyFile.h
namespace MyNamespace {
  int some_function();
}

// MyFile.cpp
using MyNamespace;
int some_function() {
  return 42;
}
```

Comment: Of course, that's not a method but a free function. </nitpick>

Answer (score 1):

You declare them the same way you would in `C`.  It can be within a namespace or outside of a namespace.  There is no difference other than the fact that they are not in a class.

If you want to use the functions in `C` later you should prepend them with `extern "C"`.

`extern "C" void foo();`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from writing *free functions*. If you think that a function should be global then free functions are quite appropriate.

Comment: let's say we have our main function in a different file and inside it we need to call these free function, so what should I do to have free functions in some other file that I will include it later in my main file ?? I mean should I make a hpp file where my free functions are implemented there ( as static inline functions maybe ) ?

Comment: yes, just include the file header file where you have the free funs in main file.

Answer (score 1):

You should place them in a namespace. Naveen's example is spot on.

As an additional note, if you wish to hide certain functions or data units within the namespace (thereby mimicking 'private' access), place those functions and data units in an anonymous namespace, nested within the parent namespace. For example:

```
namespace Foo
{
    publicFunction1();
    publicFunction2();

    namespace
    {
        privateFunction1();
        std::vector<Bar> privateData;
    }
}
```

Items within a nested, anonymous namespace are only accessible to the items within the parent namespace. I've found this to be singularly useful.

Comment: But don't put anonymous namespaces in headers.

Comment: Methods declared in an anonymous namespace in global scope are also available in that particular translation unit, FYI.